# How to repeat a computation for every column?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a dataset which looks like the following:

```
V1 V2 V3 ...
1  1  2 ...
1  1  2 ...
2  3  NA...
NA 2  1 ...
2  1  3 ...
```

it contains 2535 columns and I want to use the following index for all columns. I've managed to compute the index for the first column.

```
 ((max(table(df$V1)))-0.5*
             ((table(df$V1)["1"]+table(df$V1)["2"]+table(df$V1)["3"])
              - (max(table(df$V1)))))/(table(df$V1)["1"]+table(df$V1)["2"]+table(df$V1)["3"])
```

Is there a way how to compute the index for every 2535 of the columns? I thought about using a loop but didn't manage to write one...

Comment: What's the ultimate goal of your loop?

Comment: I need the index for every column and thereafter want to compute the mean. My problem at the moment is how to write a loop with that index

Comment: Is there any reason(except learning purposes) why you'd prefer not to use already available functions?

Comment: The reason is that this index does not exist as an already available function. I've managed to put this index into r any apply it to one column but my question is how to write a loop that does it for all columns

Comment: @AlexanderKlein Can you show the expected output based on the input you provided? I am not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve and there might be a more efficient way to do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the tidyverse package dplyr, specifically `mutate_at` or `mutate_if`.

What is your function? i.e. what is the operation you want to do on every column?

If you want to do this on ALL numeric columns in the data:

```
library(tidyverse)
mutate_if(data, is.numeric, your_function)


data = data.frame(V1 = sample(1:5, 10, replace = T),
    V2 = sample(1:5, 10, replace = T),
    V3 = sample(1:5, 10, replace = T))

mutate_if(data, is.numeric, mean) %>% unique()

       V1  V2  V3
    1 2.9 2.4 2.7
```